# Programatically Start/Stop Azure Reporting Services

Tags: azure, reporting-services

I have a client who is looking to move their SSRS instance up to Azure to make the ad-hoc reports available to internet. Due to their size and budget leaving the Azure Reporting service up 100% of the time is not really a viable option.

Ideally we would like the ability to spin up the service, run the report, publish the report, and then spin down the service with minimal manual process. The majority of the users of the report are not technically savvy.

The new Azure management portal does not allow for management of Reporting services, and the old management portal only has create / destroy instance. So its always on or nothing.

Has anyone else ventured down this rabbit hole and automated the process through the Azure API or is this even possible?

Comment: I don't this there is a public API at the moment. You can only have one report server per subscription anyway, so it's something you either have on/off. I agree, it would be good to do this via an API, and save money.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the concenses from over at MSDN. Posted to their forums " Evan Basalik on Tue, 11 Dec 2012 02:46:51


We are actively working on a new pricing model for Windows Azure SQL reporting that will better serve customers who have lower volume reporting needs. We expect to publish information on the new pricing model in the next couple weeks.  We wish to thank all of the users who provided feedback about this topic.  We’re working to address your feedback.

Evan